# returning an object inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to not have to write additional functions to populate the areas_of_interest variable, can I do it like so?

```
function prepareResults() {

    var area_of_interest = $('.checkboxes-wr').find("li");

    if (area_of_interest.length) {

        $.each(area_of_interest, function(x){

            results.items[x] = {
                'id' : $(this).attr("id"),
                'title' : $(this).find("h6").text().trim(),
                'areas_of_interest' : function() {
                    return {'test' : 'test'};
                },
                'potential_treatments' : {}
            }


        });

    }

}
```

Comment: It depends on what exactly you need the function to do. In this case you could simply make store the function in a variable outside of the `$.each` (or even outside of `populateResults`) and reference that variable in the result object. However, if you need to use a particular variable value inside the function (i.e. a *closure*) then you'll need to declare it the function in the appropriate place.

Comment: i need access to the "x" variable defined during the loop, not sure what to do

Comment: i need to build a object that would be tied to areas of interest that would have all the checkboxes under the li that its looping through

Comment: In that case, yes, it will need be defined within the `$.each` (within the scope of `x`).

Comment: can it be a function , can it return and object or does it need to be done a different way?

Comment: Does  `areas_of_interest` actually needs to be invokable like a function? Or do you just need the one-time results of calling the function? In other words, would `areas_of_interest: {'test' : 'test'}` be okay for this case?

Answer (score 0):

this worked:

function prepareResults() {

```
    var area_of_interest = $('.checkboxes-wr').find("li");

    if (area_of_interest.length) {

        $.each(area_of_interest, function(x){

            var interests = function(x) {
                return {'test' : x}
            }

            results.items[x] = {
                'id' : $(this).attr("id"),
                'title' : $(this).find("h6").text().trim(),
                'areas_of_interest' : interests(x),
                'potential_treatments' : {}
            }


        });

    }

}
```

thanks to everyone who helped in the comments above.